# WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set (netbeans)

Tags: java, xubuntu, jdk

I was trying to install Netbeans in Xubuntu. I had installed Netbeans using Snapd.

```bsh
sudo snap install netbeans --classic
```

I was trying to start Netbeans then I got an error which was looking like this

```bsh
netbeans
```

> can't find JDK (I completely don't remember the error but I had fixed it)

I had solved it this way

```bsh
$which javac
/usr/bin/javac
```

```bsh
netbeans_jdkhome='/usr/bin/javac'
```

Then when I try to start netbeans again I get the error.

```bsh
netbeans
/snap/netbeans/50/netbeans/platform/lib/nbexec: WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set
```

I had quick search in DuckDuckGo. I didn't search in Google for "safety". I couldn't find any related problem in DuckDuckGo.

**Note** : I was using Java in Android Studio. But I couldn't find java in my system that's why I had to install it again. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-16-jdk-headless`WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set (netbeans)

[Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246362/sam) mentioned in SO that it is X11 related issue. And my question got nothing in SO that's why I had deleted it there and asking it here as Sam mentioned in comment. I had never faced X11 issue earlier that's why I don't have any idea what I should do.

[In the thread](https://software.codidact.com/comments/thread/4585#comment-13797) Celtschk said to execute `export DISPLAY=:0.0`, after executing that I got another issue.

```bsh
netbeans
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2387)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:310)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2392)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:808)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:58)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createGE(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:36)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:93)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:84)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:106)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:228)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:98)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

I thought I am getting the error cause netbeans couldn't find JDK. So I had executed it again

```bsh
netbeans_jdkhome='/usr/bin/javac'
```

although I still get the same error.

Comment: are you logged into the Xubuntu GUI or one of the Virtual Consoles?

Comment: @puwlah I am not using Virtual Consoles. I am directly using Xubuntu and in Xubuntu GUI

Comment: although you had mentioned using Duckduckgo, that could have been on another device/from a text-browser. so clarified. Can you please share the output of `echo $DISPLAY?`

Comment: @puwlah `echo $DISPLAY`
`:0.0` I think I have changed it after executing that command... which I mentioned at last in OP

Comment: You could have been launching it from another shell process, in which case the value of DISPLAY wouldn't get inherited.

Comment: @puwlah I am turned on another Terminal. And executed `echo $DISPLAY` although I got same output

Comment: netbeans_jdkhome should not refer to an executable, but to the location of a JDK

Comment: openjdk-16-jdk-headless? I wouldn't go for headless when I needed to display something. Also, something more recent than 16?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I was trying to do it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670663/hash-sum-mismatch

Comment: after you try what @GerardH.Pille suggested, please see see if these posts helps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/593627/how-to-set-new-jdk-home-in-netbeans-ide-after-java-update-netbeans-ide-refuses  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464220

Comment: @puwlah Oops! I wasn't talking about it... I faced Hash Sum mismatch error that's why I couldn't install that... And I have idea of `netbeans_jdkhome`

Comment: been a while since I have used Ubuntu. the other question you linked to doesn't mention the order in which you tried doing those things. run in the following order `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* ; sudo apt clean ; sudo apt update ` then see if the hash-sum mismatch persists.

Comment: @puwlah I had executed them earlier even I have tried again. Still facing the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129993/discussion-between-puwlah-and-istiak-shovon).

Comment: check my comments in chat